# Addressing the address of a string literal in C

Tags: c, string, literals

```
char **s = &"Is this valid?";
```

Is obtaining the address at which the address of a string literal is stored allowed in C?
I know that the string literal is stored in the .rodata datasegment. However, obtaining the address of that address doesn't make sense.

It should be noted that gcc compiles this and produces a working executable.

Comment: It doesn't with `-Wall -Werror`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your example is not valid:

```
char **s = &"Is this valid?";   // Not valid, wrong type
```

This is valid:

```
char (*s)[15] = &"Is this valid?";  // OK
```

The type of `"Is this valid?"` is `char[15]`. The type of a pointer to an array 15 of `char` is `char (*)[15]`. So the type of `&"Is this valid?"` is `char (*)[15]`.

The type of a string literal is `char[N+1]` where `N` is the length of the string.

Answer (score 3):

The type of `&"Is this valid?"` is `char (*)[15]` (i.e. a pointer to a length-15 array of `char`).

Your code is invalid, as GCC will tell you if you compile with `-Wall`.